# Delete Multiple rows based on criteria from Multiple CSV files in a Folder

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2007

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_Rows_From_CSV_Files()

    Dim source_folder_name As String
    source_folder_name = "C:\Users\Siraj\Documents\CSV FILES\" 'change the path to the source folder accordingly

    If Right(source_folder_name, 1) <> "\" Then
        source_folder_name = source_folder_name & "\"
    End If

    If Len(source_folder_name) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path to the source folder is invalid!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Path"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rows_to_delete As Variant
    rows_to_delete = Array("SM", "BE") 'change and/or add row headers as desired

    Dim current_filename As String
    current_filename = Dir(source_folder_name & "*.csv", vbNormal)

    Dim file_count As Long
    While Len(current_filename) > 0
        file_count = file_count + 1
        Delete_rows_from_CSV_File source_folder_name & current_filename, rows_to_delete
        current_filename = Dir
    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Number of files processed: " & file_count, vbInformation, "Files Processed"

End Sub

Private Sub Delete_rows_from_CSV_File(ByVal source_filename As String, ByVal rows_to_delete As Variant)

    Dim source_workbook As Workbook
    Set source_workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=source_filename)

    Dim source_worksheet As Worksheet
    Set source_worksheet = source_workbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim row_found As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(rows_to_delete) To UBound(rows_to_delete)
        Set row_found = source_worksheet.Columns(2).Find(what:=rows_to_delete(i), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not row_found Is Nothing Then
            row_found.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    source_workbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

[image: Delete Multiple Rows from Multiple CSV files]Hello Friends, I am looking for a VBA code, which deletes Multiple rows based on Criteria from all CSV files in a Folder. Please Help.

Comment: You need to share the script you're writing so we can help. It's unclear where you are getting stuck

Comment: Hello Dave, as requested by you I have uploaded the script for you to review and modify

Comment: What part of the code isn't working